# how to pass data in UIPageViewController in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

> i am new to Xcode.
>
> i want to create a  app with Single view with `UIPageViewController` .
>
> In this its have 5 screen.
>
> First screen have a textfield and second screen have label and textfield and so on.
>
> when user enter a text in textfield and scroll then textfield data (means text) of first 
>   screen  to second screen label and so on.
>
> please tell me the answer i searched every where on next even stackoverflow.com and nothing
>   found like that.
>
> please help me.

Comment: you can use NSUserDefault for saving data when disappear called and can get it when will appear method called.

Comment: @PawanSharma if u r satisfied with my answer, accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first take a `UIPageViewController` and set `storyboard ID` in IB and one otherview controller which is a simple UIViewController but remember its name as a `PageContentViewController` i.e., this viewcontroller holds the 5 viewcontrollers u want to show.

in `PageContentViewController` class declare a `UIPageViewController *pageViewController;`
and in `viewWillAppear:` initialise it with its storyboardID like this

`pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyboardID"];`

then import the 5 viewcontroller classes into this `PageViewController` class and create objects for it like this

`#import "ViewController1";`

`#import "ViewController2";`

`#import "ViewController3";`

`#import "ViewController4";`

`#import "ViewController5";`

and in interface create objects

`ViewController1 *vcObj1;`

`ViewController2 *vcObj2;`

`ViewController3 *vcObj3;`

`ViewController4 *vcObj4;`

`ViewController5 *vcObj5;`

and now in .m file set these 5 viewcontrollers as an objects in an array in `viewWillAppear:` method like this

`[self setViewControllers:@[vcObj1, vcObj2, vcObj3, vcObj4, vcObj5]
                   direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                    animated:NO
                  completion:NULL];`

```
[self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
[self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
[self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

now u have to set pageviewcontroller delegate to the pagecontentviewcontroller class and write the delegate methods in .m file

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
    return vcObj1;
}
else if(index == 1) {
    return vcObj2;
}
else if(index == 2) {
    return vcObj3;
}
else if(index == 3){
    return vcObj4;
}
else if(index == 4) {
    return vcObj5;
}
index--;
return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

if (index == NSNotFound) {
    return nil;
}

index++;
if (index == 0) {
    return vcObj5;
}
else if(index == 1) {
    return vcObj4;
}
else if(index == 2) {
    return vcObj3;
}
else if(index == 3){
    return vcObj2;
}
else if(index == 4) {
    return vcObj1;
}
index++;
return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}
```

if u have written these two delegates method correctly ur functionality is done because these two are the major ones totally controlling the pageviewcontroller. i'm not sure about the indexes, just trial it once and change the indexes according to ur requirement.

Happy coding

Comment: but i am not getting [self setViewController...] in my ViewWill Appear...

Comment: Can u please tell me in which class's .m file i have to do this???

Comment: can any one else tell me how to pass data when user scroll.

Comment: i accpect your answer but you do not reply again

Comment: arre @sreekanthk tune jo code diya wo toh chala hi nahi error hi error

Comment: @PawanSharma in pagecontentviewcontroller.m file